# How can I read and write Image outside tomcat webapps folder using java

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, primefaces

**I want to save and retrieve image in my local pc folder (like as E:/CustomImage/Images/) outside tomcat.**

**This is my service class**

```
public class ImgUpload_Impl implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 public void uploadImg(String imgPath, String fileName,UploadedFile uploadFile){
 ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
String filepath = servletContext.getRealPath("/Images/"+imgPath) + File.separator + fileName;
try
   {
    InputStream is;
   try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filepath))) {
    is = uploadFile.getInputstream();
            int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int a;
            while (true) {
            a = is.read(buffer);

                if (a < 0) {
                    break;
                }

                fos.write(buffer, 0, a);

                fos.flush();
            }  
        }
       is.close();
      } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ImgUpload_Impl : uploadImg : "+e.getMessage());
    }
 }

}
```

**This is my controller class**

```
@ManagedBean
@Scope("session")
@Controller(value = "studentMB")
public class StudentMB{
private UploadedFile uploadedFile;
ImgUpLoad servicedao = new ImgUpload_Impl();

public void doRegistration(){
try{
 boolean imageContentType=servicedao.checkImageContenType(this.uploadedFile);
  if (!this.uploadedFile.getFileName().equals("") && imageContentType) {
  String imageFileName=stdRegBasicInfo.getStudentID()+"_stdimg.jpg";
   this.stdRegBasicInfo.setStudentName(imageFileName);//Here image name are save in database
    servicedao.uploadImgHeightWidth200("studentImage", imageFileName, this.uploadedFile);
 }
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
    return uploadedFile;
}

public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
}

}
```

**This is view page**

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/WEB-INF/template/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>
        <p:outputLabel value="Student Image" />
        <p:fileUpload value="#{studentMB.uploadedFile}" skinSimple="true" 
          allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" mode="simple" />

        <p:commandButton value="Save" styleClass="btnSave" ajax="false"
            style="margin-left:12px" action="#{studentMB.doRegistration}"
            update="singlestd" icon="fa fa-save" />
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

**When I upload and save image then Image save** 
*E:\Eduman.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\EduManager4\Images\studentImage\100122066717_stdimg.jpg*  **directory**

**But I want to save Image** *E:\CustomImage\Images* **directory**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To make your code working as expected you need to modify `class ImgUpload_Impl` by replacing line

```
String filepath = servletContext.getRealPath("/Images/"+imgPath) + File.separator + fileName;
```

with this one

```
String filepath = "E:\\CustomImage\\Images\\"+imgPath + File.separator + fileName;
```

Do not forget to make sure that folder *E:\CustomImage\Images\studentImage* actually exist. If it doesn't exist create it manually or programmatically from your code.

Since you will probably need to read uploaded image later, I would recommend that you define string `"E:\\CustomImage\\Images\\"` as global constant (static final) variable or to move it in some settings file if you have it.
On that way you will be able to maintain your code easier and have configurable path to your images if some day you have a need to change it.

Comment: I already try String filepath = "E:\\CustomImage\\Images\\"+imgPath + File.separator + fileName; but file not save

Comment: when I apply above solution then problem is  File Path E:\CustomImage\Images\studentImage\100122067017_stdimg.jpg
ImgUpload_Impl : uploadImg : E:\CustomImage\Images\studentImage\100122067017_stdimg.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: @Md.NasirUddin you need to manually create folder E:\CustomImage\Images\studentImage. I will update my answer.